# Bypass VPN for local network

Tags: iptables, routing, vpn

I'm using a VPN service (ProtonVPN) through their CLI (`protonvpn`) on my GNU/Linux computer (NixOS).

The problems is that it reroute all my traffic, including my local-network traffic, causing issues.

I have made few attempts, first, after comparing `ip route show table all scope link`, I have noticed that only those two lines were added:

```
xx.xx.0.0/16 dev proton0 proto kernel src xx.xx.0.4
broadcast xx.xx.255.255 dev proton0 table local proto kernel src xx.xx.0.4
```

I've also tried to get the route of another computer on my network:

```
$ ip route get 192.168.0.yy
192.168.0.yy dev eno1 src 192.168.0.xx uid 1000 
    cache
```

Then, I have tried to enforce the route with `ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev eno1` but it changed nothing.

Lastly, I have compared `ip route show table all`, which gave me these additional lines:

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.86.0.1 dev proton0
xx.xx.0.0/16 dev proton0 proto kernel scope link src xx.xx.0.4
128.0.0.0/1 via xx.xx.0.1 dev proton0
yy.yy.yy.yy via 192.168.0.254 dev eno1
local xx.xx.0.4 dev proton0 table local proto kernel scope host src xx.xx.0.4
broadcast xx.xx.255.255 dev proton0 table local proto kernel scope link src xx.xx.0.4
```

What is the right approach to avoid the VPN for the local network?

Comment: Enable "split tunnelling". Alternatively, if Proton is based on OpenVPN then edit the client configuration file to comment out the `redirect-gateway def1`

Comment: When you did "ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev eno1", can you confirm that there was no error message, but the route never showed up in the routing table?  That could mean that the ProtonVPN application is monitoring your routing table and deleting anything that you add.  Anyconnect application also does this and there are ways to work around it.  What is the output from "ip rule show"?